# Change theme for single user mahapps metro control

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have built a WPF config-tool with mahapps.metro (version 1.5!) that lets the user configure my other apps. On one of the views I let the user define the styles. To make it more easy to decide which style fits, I created a control that looks like the other apps in miniature. The idea is to set the defined style to this preview.

So, is it possible to change the theme for a single UserControl dynamical?  All I have found is the ThemeManager class, but with that I change the theme for the complete app or the complete current window and not only for the one control within my current window:

```
ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, …)
```

I am open for other (practical) solutions. But it has to be part of same window, to have a dialog or preview popup is no acceptable solution.

Comment: Please read this maybe helpful [Styles](https://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html#window) this is from the officially website from MahApps to change the style of the program.

Answer (score 0):

`ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle` can accept `Window` as the first parameter. So instead of using `UserControl` you can make `Window` and in this window, you can show a new style:

```
public partial class Window1 : MetroWindow
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(this,
            ThemeManager.GetAccent("Orange"),
            ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseLight"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be a solution. But I cannot include the Window within the current window like a UserControl.

Comment: Yes, you can't. You should create a new instance of this `Window` and show it via `Show` or `ShowDialog` methods. In the constructor of this window, you can pass parameters of the new theme that you want to show to the user.

Comment: :-( but this is what I need: just one control within current window changes the style